# WCF - 400 Bad request - 2 Days configuring

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to solve my problem when I send class Product (including a binary[] Picture). If I send a Product containing a picture of around 14KB it works, but if I increase the size to 17KB I get the error message:

"The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Because it works with smaller pictures I think it is something wrong with my configurations.

Client (winform) app.config:
http://www.copypastecode.com/157335/

Server web.config:
http://www.copypastecode.com/157339/

I've tried to increased every value (maxBufferSize, maxReceivedMessageSize..) to MAX without any progress?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending array you should check

> maxArrayLength

setting as you most probably hit this limit. What is the length of your array when with 17kb file?
But in general, the best way to upload \ download files are stream upload \ download endpoints

Comment: But i've already set my maxArrayLength="2000000" on the server side..still get an error: "There was an error deserializing the object of type Product. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exeeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader".

Comment: @user1145261 You should set it both on client and server

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding the DataContractSerializer element in your serviceBehaviour element to define the maxItemsInObjectGraph as shown below

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

Also try to add [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service and see the trace log for the exact reason on why the request is failing.

If your total request length is exceeding 4MB then make sure you have the below:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I've added the code on the server-side but still get an error: "There was an error deserializing the object of type Product. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exeeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader". But i've already set my maxArrayLength="2000000" on the server side..

Comment: You need to have the same value on both client and server. Also noticed that you are using webhttpbinding on server and basichttpbinding on client. Make sure you configure the setting for each binding individually and use the binding to access the service